# How to make a JSON String using the key/value from the Map

Tags: java, json, dictionary

I am trying to create a JSON String using the corresponding key/value pair. In the below code, I am trying to iterate the list of `AttributeValue` and then I am trying to makie the JSON String using the `al.getValue map`.

```
private <T> String createJsonWithEscCharacters(List<AttributeValue<T>> list) {

    StringBuilder keyValue = new StringBuilder();

    if (list != null) {
        for (AttributeValue<?> al: list) {

            keyValue.append("\"").append("v").append("\"").append(":").append(" {");

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : ((Map<String, String>) al.getValue()).entrySet()) {
                keyValue.append("\"").append(entry.getKey()).append("\"");
                keyValue.append(":").append(" \"").append(entry.getValue()).append("\"").append(",");
                System.out.println(keyValue);
            }

        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

When I inspect on `al`, I see `value` as `LinkedHashMap<K,V>` and when I print `al.getValue()`, it gives me this-

```
{predictedCatRev=0;101;1,1;201;2, predictedOvrallRev=77;2,0;1,16;3, sitePrftblty=77;2,0;1671679, topByrGms=12345.67, usrCurncy=1, vbsTopByrGmb=167167.67}
```

So that means, I can iterate the `al.getValue()` map and use those `key/value pair` to make the JSON String.

Now I am trying to make a JSON String by iterating the `al.getValue()` map. So the JSON String should look something like this after iterating the `al.getValue()` map-

```
{
 "lv": [
  {
   "v": {
    "predictedCatRev": "0;101;1,1;201;2",
    "predictedOvrallRev": "77;2,0;1,16;3",
    "sitePrftblty": "77;2,0;1671679",
    "topByrGms": "12345.67",
    "usrCurncy": "1",
    "vbsTopByrGmb": "167167.67"
   }
  }
 ],
}
```

I am wondering what is the cleanest way to do this? In my above code, I am not fully able to make the above JSON String but whatever code I have above, it is able to make slight portion of JSON String in the way I needed but the not full JSON String in the way, I am looking for. Can anyone help me on this like what will be the cleanest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use serialization libraries like GSON which does all this for you?

Comment: You know you can create a JSONObject from a Map, right?  See [this](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.util.Map))

Comment: I can use various JSON libraries but those won't give me `lv` and `v` in the way I am looking in my actual `JSONString`. Meaning, I need to append those, `lv and v` in my actual `JSONString`

Comment: I fail to see why you can't use a library. You're making this way to complicated.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure what exact task you're working, but there are many JSON libraries for Java which can do this for you such as [json in java](http://json.org/java/) and [google-gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).   For example, in json in java, once you have filled all the values in its [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html), then converting it into JSON string is fairly easy:

```
JSONObject.toString();  // compact JSON string
JSONObject.toString(int indent);  // easier readable format with indention.
```

For example, in your case, you may create a JSONObject like the following and invoke its toString() function.  This can safe your time from formatting string to fit the JSON format:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
Map<String, String> strStrMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

strStrMap.put("hello", "world");
strStrMap.put("here is", "an example");

jsonObject.put("myMap", strStrMap);

System.out.println(jsonObject.toString(2));
```

and here is its output:

```
{"myMap": {
  "hello": "world",
  "here is": "an example"
}}
```

Comment: I can use various JSON libraries but those won't give me lv and v in the way I am looking in my actual JSONString. Meaning, I need to append those, lv and v in my actual JSONString

Comment: @user21973: I don't understand.  If you create the right json object, then it will certainly generate the right output for you ...

Comment: I'm on the same page as you are @keelar.  The OP is making this **WAY** too complicated.  This should be extremely straightforward and should **not** involve any of the headaches involved with manually constructing a JSON string.

Answer (score 4):

You can just do something like this:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject rootJo = new JSONObject();

for (AttributeValue<?> al : list) {
    JSONObject mapJo = new JSONObject(al.getValue());
    rootJo.put("v", mapJo);
}
```

In other words:

- create a new (empty) JSONObject named *rootJo* (root JSON object)
- iterate over your list of maps
- for each element in the list, convert the map into a JSONObject (using a library)
- add a new property to *rootJo*  (the key will be `v`)
- set the value of `v` to the JSONObject that was created from the map

Maybe I'm missing something, but I would replace your entire method with this:

```
/**
 *  Creates a JSON object from a list of attributes that
 *  have maps as their values.
 */

private JSONObject toJson(List<AttributeValue<?>> attList) {
    if (attList == null) {
        return null;
    }
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray  ja = new JSONArray();
    for (AttributeValue<?> att : attList) {
        JSONObject mapJo = new JSONObject(att.getValue());
        ja.put("v", mapJo);
    }
    jo.put("lv", ja);
    return jo;
}
```

You should also make it typesafe, but I'll leave the finer details to you...

(plus I'm not sure what an AttributeValue is... can't find it anywhere)

Answer (score 2):

Use Jackson.  It's lightweight and faster than Gson.  It also isn't known to be bundled by OEMs, which can mess with your classpath.

Comment: I can use various JSON libraries but those won't give me lv and v in the way I am looking in my actual JSONString. Meaning, I need to append those, lv and v in my actual JSONString

Comment: @user21973 - Yes, they will.  You just have to use the libraries properly ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When using google gson.

```
var getRowData =
[{
    "dayOfWeek": "Sun",
    "date": "11-Mar-2012",
    "los": "1",
    "specialEvent": "",
    "lrv": "0"
},
{
    "dayOfWeek": "Mon",
    "date": "",
    "los": "2",
    "specialEvent": "",
    "lrv": "0.16"
}];

    JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(request.getParameter("getRowData"));
     JsonArray  jsonArray = root.getAsJsonArray();
     JsonObject  jsonObject1 = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
     String dayOfWeek = jsonObject1.get("dayOfWeek").toString();
```

// when using jackson

```
    JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
              ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          JsonParser jp = f.createJsonParser(getRowData);
          // advance stream to START_ARRAY first:
          jp.nextToken();
          // and then each time, advance to opening START_OBJECT
         while (jp.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            Map<String,Object> userData = mapper.readValue(jp, Map.class);
            userData.get("dayOfWeek");
            // process
           // after binding, stream points to closing END_OBJECT
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to send a JSON back as a response to the calling request.. You could use the Spring framework where it automatically converts the Map object to JSON using Jackson converter. You will need to just use the annotation @ResponseBody for the return type. You can read more on the Spring 3 documentation.

Comment: I can use various JSON libraries but those won't give me lv and v in the way I am looking in my actual JSONString. Meaning, I need to append those, lv and v in my actual JSONString

Comment: it would give you the json you are looking at if you have the map created as "v" and list of "v" as lv.
so you would have a main map for json -
Map jsonMap = new HasMap();
jsonMap.put("lv", list of v);

Returning the jsonMap would give you the json by Jackson...